# How to Use Firefox Persona .p12 Certificates with Playwright for Automated Testing?

Tags: c#, .net, firefox, certificate, playwright

I'm transitioning automated tests from Selenium to Playwright and facing issues with using Firefox persona certificates (.p12 files) for user authentication in a .NET web application. Previously, with Selenium, we directly installed persona certificates into Firefox by simply clicking the .p12 files and going through the installation wizard. However, I'm not aware of anyway to redirect this wizard to instead install these to the Playwright-controlled instance of the browsers.

Our web application requires login using credentials that we can simulate using these persona certificates to avoid needing to choose them manually which allows them to be run in our CI/CD pipeline, so we must find a way to integrate this authentication method within our Playwright tests. Additionally, we're in a pretty closed environment so we don't have a lot of options to install or use additional tools. We don't even have access to the Firefox command line tools.

Is there a way to programmatically handle these persona certificates using Playwright, possibly by configuring the browser context or some other means? Any guidance or workarounds would be greatly appreciated!